# Request URI Match and Redirect to Specific Link htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all root users to a specific link eg: `example.com` to `example.com/en1` which an `index.php` file, so if any user type `example.com/en2 or en3 or en100` will redirect to `example.com/en1`

I have tried this code

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "en1") == false){
    header('Location: en1');
}
```

But the problem is, when I type `en2 or en100` it shows 404 error not redirecting to `en1`

Also tried htaccess

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /en1
RewriteRule en1 index.php
```

But no luck!

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRules` like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirect / to /en1
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en1 [R,L]
#redirect /en123 to /en1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en1$
RewriteRule ^en[0-9]+ https://example.com/en1 [L,R]
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: It only works till /en9 from /en10 it does not redirect

Comment: @K.Mughal sorry there a typo. Try the updated version now.